# Using jQuery Templates with Autocomplete and NOT using ul/li

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

@swatkins gave a fantastic answer to his own question about using jQuery templates with jquery UI's autocomplete here: [Is there a way to use jQuery templates (official plugin) with jQuery UI Autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288232/is-there-a-way-to-use-jquery-templates-official-plugin-with-jquery-ui-autocomp)

My question builds off of that.

Basically i am wondering how would one go about building an autocomplete, with jQuery templates, that does not use any sort of lists?

The reason i ask is i'd like to display a lot of information in a small space and styling it with lists does not seem to allow this... Also, i'm just really curious :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list item, but nest the html to display inside of it. Then, you can style the list items to show in columns if you'd like.

Here's my updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XXeDd/8/

Comment: thanks for updating the jsfiddle but I don't think this is "legal" html.  Based on http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-ul-element.html#the-ul-element I'm understanding the only valid child to be an `li`.  It seems like the `.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem` expects a UL to be present and i think this is where my confusion lives :)

Comment: OK, if you take the "purist" route - then semantically, using a div in this instance is the wrong solution. After all, you're displaying a "list" of results with the autocomplete - so shouldn't you be using a list item to display each result? Technically, you can place other elements inside a list element, so you could have `<li><div class="styleme"><p>whatever</p></div></li>` as each result.

Comment: Again, thank you for responding. I see what you're saying.  My intent is to create something like Stack's listing of suggested tags that appear when adding tags to a question... So with that said i think that a list is not ideal.  Based on your response though, it sounds like we are FORCED to append whatever element we produce to a UL?

Comment: You can achieve the exact same result of the SO tag autosuggest with list items just as easily as with div elements. You decide the css applied to the list items, so the underlying architecture is irrelevant to what you want to display. Just return list items with the html you need to display in each result, and work some css magic to emulate the SO autosuggest look.

Comment: that is beautiful!  Also after further reading it appears that it's legal to nest Divs inside of LIs ( source: http://learningforlife.fsu.edu/webmaster/references/xhtml/tags/list/li.cfm )  Thanks for taking the time to respond and build a jsfiddle.  If you update your original answer i will mark it as the correct answer.  this will work great. thanks 2x